# "LinkAssemblies" task failed while compiling

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I wrote some really simple code to test out Xamarin capabilities and ran into this problem

I already tried to Clean Solution and Project, Re-written all code in fresh project, Moved project to C: disk

```
Error       The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'JvlivsSays, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'JvlivsSays.dll'
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.GetAssembly(String fileName)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() JvlivsSays
```

"JvlivsSays" is project and solution name, There is no other errors

Comment: Have you already tried following this link advices? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/troubleshooting/questions/android-linkassemblies-error

Comment: Yes but without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that this error appears when there is any other errors, in my case when i fixed typo in .axml layout file, everything worked as it should.